# Installing virtualbox from .deb gives error: faulty packages are in "keep as is" mode

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, dpkg, dependencies

I would like to install virtualbox to use genymotion. I downloaded the .deb package. I get this error when I run the command `sudo apt install ./virtualbox`.

```
The following packages contain unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-7.0: Dependency: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6 will have to be installed
                  Dependency: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.1) but 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6 should be installed
                  Dependent: libqt5dbus5 (>= 5.14.1) but 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6 should be installed
                  Dependent: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.14.1) but 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6 should be installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.14.1) but it is not installable
                  Dependent: libqt5help5 (>= 5.15.1) but 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 should be installed
                  Dependent: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.15.1) but 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6 will have to be installed
                  Depends: libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 12) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 will have to be installed
                  Depends: libvpx7 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommended: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but will not be installed
                  Recommended: linux-image
E: Unable to fix problems, faulty packages are in "keep as is" mode.
```

I am new to Linux. My Ubuntu version is 18.04.

Comment: because I saw this method during my research

Comment: my ubuntu version is 18.04

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.

First I executed these commands:

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then I rebooted my machine and I entered:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Answer (score 0):

execute this command

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

After install your instance of virtualbox